# Trouble getting Category-wise folder names from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting folder and sub-folder data into a mysql table.
Folder names where `PARRENT FOLDER ID` is equal to `0` indicate main or top level folders, whereas a `PARRENT FOLDER ID` greater than `0` is a sub-folder.
`PARRENT FOLDER ID` column stores the Main Folder's unique id.

```
FOLDER_ID   |   FOLDER_NAME |   PARRENT_FOLDER_ID
1           |   finance     |       0
2           |   Business    |       1
3           |   MIS         |       2
4           |   2017        |       3
5           |   2018        |       3
6           |   Jan-17      |       4
7           |   Jan-18      |       5
8           |   Circulars   |       0
9           |   2017        |       8
10          |   Jan-17      |       9
```

And I want to populate folder list on page using PHP as per following format

```
Finance
-Business
--MIS
---2017
----Jan-17
---2018
----Jan-18
Circulars
-2017
--Jan-17
```

I have tried the following PHP code for displaying this information, but the results are not correct.

```
$select_folder = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from folder where p_folder_id='0'");

while ($row_folder = mysqli_fetch_array($select_folder)) {

    echo $row_folder['name']."<br>";

    $select_p_folder = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from folder where p_folder = '".$row_folder['id']."'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($select_p_folder) > 0) {

        while ($row_p_folder = mysqli_fetch_array($select_p_folder)) {
            echo "-".$row_p_folder['name']."<br>";

            $select_next_folder = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from folder where p_folder = '".$row_p_folder['id']."'");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($select_next_folder) > 0) {
                while ($row_next_folder = mysqli_fetch_array($select_next_folder)) {

                    echo "--".$row_next_folder['name']."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Why don't you fetch all your data from database, put it in an array, and then try to transform this array to your desired format, and then load it to your view, instead of nested loops with lots of database fetching processes.

Comment: Your goal is a way easier to implement if you use nested sets technique for the tree-like structures. See here https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model&amp;ved=2ahUKEwj-6faIj4zZAhWyiqYKHd82AVoQFjACegQIERAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw3mViQdhgsU3RN8ajaZRJpf